# Paypal button on my website

Tags: payment-gateway, paypal

I want to create a button on my wordpress website to integrate with pay pal so that the user have the option to choose to create account or to enter his credit card direct,and not to be directed to the pay pal site,how can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

PayPal hosted sole solution might be useful for you. Have a look at it
https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/products/website-payments-pro-hosted-solution/